# Cors Error with Infura?

Tags: web3js, infura, dapp-debugging

anyone else who tries to read smart contract data through [Infura](https://infura.io/) and process it on front-end but gets 'CORS' error? 
My DAPP works fine in Google Chrome and has no issue in fetching the smart contract data. Same on Internet Explorer. The problem is when I use Microsoft Edge that I'm getting this:

[image: Microsoft Edge Error]

My web3 implementation is correct:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';


let web3;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // metamask is running
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set up provider through infura
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    // pass url of remote node
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/censored');
  web3 = new Web3(provider);

}

export default web3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION!
I was running web3@1.0.0-beta.35 however downgrading to web3@1.0.0-beta.34 fixed it for me.

All credits go to [clementbalestrat](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1802#issuecomment-417149497)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid downgrading, the most-recent pre-release of Web3 also solves the problem. `npm i web3@2.0.0-alpha.1`

Answer (score 0):

> One possibility is that your computer is configured with an Intranet zone and that Intranet zone is dependent on a proxy configuration script: [The Intranet Zone](https://web.archive.org/web/20160202125024/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/06/05/the-local-intranet-security-zone.aspx). When Fiddler is running, the proxy settings are pointed at Fiddler itself.
>
> Ah, right, there's another factor at work here if you're using an Intranet site as the target of an XHR from a site in the Internet zone.
>
> Edge runs in Enhanced Protected Mode (AppContainer). That has a feature which blocks access to Private Network Resources from Internet-Zone processes. See the "Private Network resources" section of [Understanding Enhanced Protected Mode](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206145918/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx) for more details.

Source: [Understanding Enhanced Protected Mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/03/23/understanding-enhanced-protected-mode/)

Comment: What bothers me is that it worked for weeks and now out of nowhere it stopped. I'm considering setting it up through a [proxy](https://coursework.vschool.io/setting-up-a-full-stack-react-application/) but I still want to see if others have any solutions