# Cross Origin Blocked? Setting up Infura provider

Tags: web3js, infura, cors

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const loadWeb3 = async () => {
      const web3 = new Web3(
        new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/censored")
      );

      let n = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
      setBN(n);
    };

    loadWeb3();
  }, []);
```

here's is the snippet from my react app...

console says Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mainnet.infura.io/censored (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://localhost:8100’).

Answer (score 2):

I think your question already asked before here: [Cors Error with Infura?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60509/cors-error-with-infura/60533)

If you are using web3@1.0.0-beta.35, you could try downgrading your web3 version to 1.0.0-beta.35.

The detail explaination you could find [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1802#issuecomment-417149497)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of that answer here.  Answers consisting only of links are not particularly helpful and are liable to be deleted.

Comment: Yes, edited my answer adding more information.

Comment: I am using web3@^1.2.6 tho